# How to load data in MATLAB from current script folder?

Tags: matlab, file-io, matlab-load

There is a script myScript.m, under D:\myProjects, so its location is D:\myProjects\myScript.m

I want to load a .dat file at D:\myProjects\myData\someData.dat

How do I use the load() function **without** using the absolute path like

```
data = load('D:\myProjects\myData\someData.dat')   % something I do not want
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/04/01/be-absolute-about-your-relative-path-with-getfullpath/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = load('myData\someData.dat')
```

Use a relative path. This assumes you are executing the program from it's home directory D:\myProjects.

If you need to call the script from different folders you should pass the path to the .dat as an [argument to the script.](http://kawahara.ca/how-to-run-a-matlab-functionscript-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: What if not running from its home directory? It is a script, not really a function

Comment: This is not working ! I have just checked that on Matlab R2012b !

Comment: Can you put what you are doing into a pastebin or something? We need more info to help you.